# skip iteration outer loop in an inner loop

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have two loops and when I iterating in my inner loop, I want to skip iteration for the outer loop according to my condition; `continue;` is only skips inner loop. Any idea?

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    if (row[i].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                        //skip iteration to outer loop. Go to next row.
                }
 }
```

Comment: You cannot jump to the next outer-loop-iteration until your inner loop ended. Is this a problem for you? If not, you can use `break`.
Are there other instructions behind your inner loop which are inside the outer-loop too?

Comment: @cihata87 write break; it will break inner loop and continue the outer loop

Comment: @Akanksha break; breaks from inner loop but it continues under for loop. I want to go to the } of foreach loop so I can check next row.

Answer (score 2):

I think break will serve the purpos, if you want to get out of the inner loop and continue with the next row of the outer loop

```
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                if (row[i].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                    break;
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 6).TakeWhile(n => !row[n].Equals(DBNull.Value)))
    {
        // no need for `if` at all now.
    }
}
```